# NumberPad Keyboard without text preview

Tags: android

My question is simple: I want to show a NumberPad keyboard on my android app **without text preview and "Done" button**. Just like the keypad that is shown on WhatsApp when user submits his phone number.
I hope the answer would be a simple one too! :)

Comment: What you had tried for this?

Comment: Try `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="phone"

Comment: My main question is :"how to HIDE text preview" on soft keyboard

Comment: @Bardia text preview means text suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with **`textNoSuggestions`**

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: NumberPassord isn't needed unless you want it to show up as * characters.  Just number is enough.   A note:  this is the right answer, but its up to the keyboard app to support this.  Some will, some will decide that they don't want to, or want to under only certain circumstances.  In that case there's no way to force it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

Comment: My main question is :"how to HIDE text preview" on soft keyboard